# Delete an empty Java package from SVN repository

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm running Eclipse 3.7.2 with Subversion 1.8.6. I have a package which I don't need any more so I deleted the package in the Package Explorer and committed the `/src` folder however got an error about one of the files in the package being out of date. I reverted, made sure all of the files were up to date and then deleted all of the files in the package, but not the package itself, and this worked great.

Now when I try and delete the empty package in Package Explorer, the package which is fully updated with the server, and commit the `/src` folder I get the error:

> org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E155011: Commit
> failed (details follow): svn: E155011: Directory 'C:...\workspace...\src\ecc' is out of date

So how can I delete this empty package?

I have read [How to properly delete Java packages under SVN control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677171/how-to-properly-delete-java-packages-under-svn-control) however our problems seems to be slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by doing a Team > Update first.  The out of date message means that an item you are
 trying to commit was not at its HEAD revision in your working copy.

Comment: Exactly. If you have to commit something that was deleted, always do a SVN Update prior to committing.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of what the error means but this seems to have worked although I was sure the package was up to date, it had the little yellow icon next to it. Thanks though.

Comment: The packages still exist after update and commit. Answer of Hendrickx works.

Answer (score 5):

This should just work, but I've known it to fail from time to time.

Just delete the folder using *Svn repository exploring*, then update the project.